# Vue: how to use component as prop doesn't display empty component no html tag of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have three components:

- `HugeBox.vue`
- `Box.vue`
- `Dog.vue`

`HugeBox` contains a `Box` which in turn contains a `Dog`:

```
HugeBox -> Box -> Dog
```

I try to pass the `Dog` to the `Box` as a prop, however it doesn't work: all that gets displayed when I open `HugeBox` is

```
Box with
```

while it should be

```
Box with Dog
```

**HugeBox.vue**:

```
<template>
    <Box :myComponent = "Dog"/>
</template>

<script>
    import Dog from '../test/Dog.vue';
    import Box from '../test/Box.vue';

    export default {
        components: {Dog, Box}
    }
</script>
```

**Box.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Box with</p>
        <component :is = "myComponent"/>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default  {
        props:  {
            myComponent:  {
                type: [String, Object],
             }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Dog.vue**:

```
<template>
    <p>Dog</p>
</template>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Vue, if you need to pass markup or other components into a child component you can use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

Slots allow you to nest components within other components, just as you do with HTML.

**HugeBox.vue**:

```
<template>
    <Box>
        <Dog/>
    </Box>
</template>

<script>
    import Dog from '../test/Dog.vue';
    import Box from '../test/Box.vue';

    export default {
        components: {Dog, Box}
    }
</script>
```

**Box.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Box with</p>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import Box from '../test/Dog.vue';
    export default  {
        props:  {
            myComponent:  {
                type: [String, Object],
             }
        },
        components: { Dog }
    }
</script>
```

The `<slot>` tag is used to specify where the nested content should be displayed.

**EDIT:**

So you *can* actually pass components as props, and display them using the `<component :is="..." />` method.

The reason that it's not working is that your original `HugeBox.vue` component doesn't have access to the `Dog` component as a template variable. You have to assign it to a data property first:

```
<template>
  <Box :myComponent="dog"/>
</template>

<script>
import Dog from "../test/Dog.vue";
import Box from "../test/Box.vue";

export default {
  components: { Box },
  data() {
    return {
      dog: Dog // assign the Dog component object to data, allowing it to be passed as a prop
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: So you replaced `<Box :myComponent = "Dog"/>` with `<Box><Dog/></Box>` and `<component :is = "myComponent"/>` with `<slot></slot>`? It seems to be working, thank you. However I want to understand why the original example doesn't work, because then I googled how to pass components as props, that approach with `<component>` tag was the one everyone recommended

Comment: @parsecer I've edited my answer to show you how to make your original method work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your `Dog` component inside your `Box` component.
Not inside your `HugeBox` component.

#### HugeBox.vue

```
<template>
    <Box :myComponent = "'Dog'"/>
</template>

<script>
    import Dog from '../test/Box.vue';

    export default {
        components: {Box}
    }
</script>
```

#### Box.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Box with</p>
        <component :is = "myComponent"/>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import Box from '../test/Dog.vue';
    export default  {
        props:  {
            myComponent:  {
                type: [String, Object],
             }
        },
        components: { Dog }
    }
</script>
```

#### Dog.vue

```
<template>
    <p>Dog</p>
</template>
```